# HTML mail displayed wrong

Tags: php, html-email

When I send html message through an mail sending it will break the design in mail account. The code is below:

```
<?php
$center_part2 = "";
$mail_ID = "exmaple.gmail.com";
$subject = "UnTouched Ticket Notification";
$headers = "From: example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$part = '<html><body>';
$part .= '<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;padding: 10px 10px 20px;width: 500px; float:left;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">';
$part1 = '<div style="width:500px;">';
$part1 .= '<div style="width:500px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">';  
$part1 .= '<div style="width:450px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc; height:auto; float:left;font-size:12px;margin-left:50px; font-weight:bold;">';
$part3 = '</div></div></div>';
$part3 .= '</body></html>';
$center_part = 'You have opened '.$inr.' tickets . But the following tickets are not updated yet ,';
$center_part2.="<div style='width:345px;color:#000000;font-size:12px;margin-left:75px; font-weight:bold; height:auto; margin-top:10px;'>"; 
    for ($k=1; $k<=70; $k++){

       $new.="<p>Ticket &#35;".$K." Last Updated  ".$K." days ".$K." hours  ago &#33;</p>";
    }
    $center_part2.=$new."</div>";
    if($mail_ID){
        $message = "";
        $center_part1 = 'Dear Admin ,'; 
        $message = $part.$center_part1.$part1.$center_part.$center_part2.$part3;
        mail($mail_ID, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
```

When I opened the gmail I get the mail like this:

[image: Screenshot]

So what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Mind posting the generated HTML in full as well?

Comment: Have you considered using templating? This is very messy and will be hard to maintain in the future.

Comment: The generated html would help. Also why are you sending it like that? there is much better ways of sending html email. Not sure if this any use : http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2681

Comment: No I need to send like this only?

Comment: Why are you using so many `<div>` tags with floats and fixed widths? Repeated `float:left` will stack the elements up side by side unless you `clear:left`. It shouldn't need to be that complicated to create the simple output where a line of text is repeated.

Comment: @MrCode, your comment should be an answer because that's definitely his problem.

Comment: @MrCode, your replay is correct it is the problem of so many div tag now i solve it .

Comment: But i have one issue now there have an `!` is appended inbetween with some rows

Comment: The ! problem is due to exceeding  the max chars per line. keep each line under 512 chars, use \n to break up the content.

Comment: @user1229903 I've posted my comments as an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post my comment as an answer as davidethell suggested, in case anyone else lands here with the same problem.

The display issue was due to the `<div>` tags having `float:left` and a fixed width, causing them to become stacked side by side where the width permitted.

The `!` problem where random `!` are inserted into the email content is due to exceeding the max characters per line. Keeping each line under 512 characters will resolve this. Use a `\n` to break up the content as required.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed  of `<div>` of the following code.

```
$part .= '<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;padding: 10px 10px 20px;width: 500px; float:left;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">';
```